# My taskbar doesn't show up after startup

Tags: 11.04, command-line, taskbar

Just upgraded to natty. This is the first time I turned on my computer to use it, it didn't show anything but my wallpaper. No side panel or taskbar. Just the wallpaper. Now, I sort of know what happened (I played around with the appearances a little).

**Can anyone give me the commands to open the login setting as well as appearance in order to change my settings back to normal? **

Note: I didn't install anything. Just changed some settings to the login screen for it not to show up or something close to that.

I would love to show you all the evidence but I'm posting this via cell phone. Please help me! I know how to open terminal it's the programming I need help with. Thanks!

Comment: Kayla - similar question and answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40133/unity-not-showing-after-11-04-upgrade-cannot-log-out-to-switch-to-classic/40142#40142

Answer (score 1):

At login screen, there's a drop-down combo box at the bottom. In that box, select `Ubuntu Classic Desktop` and then login. It appears that your GPU isn't supported by the new Unity interface.

Once you've logged into Classic Desktop, then install [unity-2d](http://packages.ubuntu.com/unity-2d) [image: Install unity-2d] to get a proper Unity experience regardless of whether your GPU supports hardware acceleration or not.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me too!

I had to figure out how to open compiz without anything but a desktop (create an icon on the desktop). Then reset the effects settings, for my desktop I have: In Desktop -> Desktop Wall, Expo, Unity Plugin, Viewport Switcher; Window Management -> All, but app switcher, put, shift switcher and ring switcher.

You can probably choose whatever you want for the other categories, but I can specify those too if need be.